# Inverted border radius css

Tags: html, css

Good afternoon.

Please help me make inverted border radius as in the image.

Below is the code.

How is this possible to implement?

I can not understand how to do this(

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```css
body {
  background: grey;
  margin: 0px!important;
}

#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#button div {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  background: yellow;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div id="button">
    <div>
      +
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should try working with SVGs.

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW I'm new to this, could you help?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question has been closed :( So, no answers can be added.

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW Could it be in the comments?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57440523/css-transparent-curved-shape-with-two-rounded-sides

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW I can’t make the cutout be on top and not on the right.