# How to make a polygon with css

Tags: css, user-interface, sass

I am trying to make the circular cutout but can't figure out how.
[Cutout around the arrow button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve7o2.png)

[close up look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZn7M.png)

Comment: Could you show us the code you have so far. Have you investigated clip path?

Comment: [This worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57440523/css-transparent-curved-shape-with-two-rounded-sides)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with 1 rectangle (`span1`) and 3 circles. And `position: absolute`

```css
.main{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background:red;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.span1{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: -25px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 25px;
  background: red;
}
.span2{
  position: absolute;
  top:25px;
  left: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.span3{
  position: absolute;
  top:-25px;
  left: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.span4{
  position: absolute;
  top:75px;
  left: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <span class="span1"></span>
  <span class="span2"></span>
  <span class="span3"></span>
  <span class="span4"></span>
</div>
```